# How to exclude a file/folder from Build in MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop

When using MonoDevelop is it possible to exclude a file or folder within a solution so that it is ignored during Builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try changing the build action on the files to None? Right click the file in the Solution pad, select Build Action, then select None. You cannot do this for a folder but you can do this for all the files.